# How can be the GeometryTransform set in the Polyline class (C# wpf)?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, transform, polyline

As far as I can understand, with the GeometryTransform I could scale the internal points without changing the actual thickness of the line and touching the Points collection.
The goal would be to set only the tranfrom for a zoom (without recreating all the points as mentioned), but I don't intend to change the line thickness with it as the RenderTransform or LayerTransform would do.

The GeometryTransform seems to be a "get" only property with an Identity content, so I can't do something like:
`line.GeometryTransform = new ScaleTransform(2.0, 2.0); // this code is invalid`

or

`((MatrixTransform)Polyline0.GeometryTransform).Matrix = new Matrix(ScaleX, 0, 0, ScaleY, 0, 0);`

Ofcourse I could recreate all the points in the Polyline container or make some extra expensive binding on the Points property, but that would be a bit overkill...
Changing the LayerTransform, RenderTransform or any parent matrix is late since it will be applied to the line thickness as well.
If the ScaleX and ScaleY would be equal, I could just recalculate the thickness as well to 1/Scale, but they can be different in my case.

Thank you!

Comment: Use a Path with a PathGeometry or StreamGeometry. Set the Transform property of the Geometry.

Comment: Way more deeper object hierarchy, but it works. I used StreamGeometry as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Could you add your answer separately so I can mark it as corret answer? Thank you!

Comment: If you check the type of a Polyline's RenderedGeometry value, you'll see that it also is a PathGeometry, so you have the deep object hierarchy anyway.